# How to send email with recent azure infrastructure deployment details

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, sendgrid, azure-rm-template

I have provisioned multiple resources in Azure by using ARM templates through the Azure DevOps CI & CD pipelines.

I have followed this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment?view=azps-5.2.0) to get the recent deployment details based on the deployment name.

I am getting the recent deployment details by using this PowerShell command.

```
    $deployments = Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName  $resourceGroupName | Sort-Object Timestamp -Descending
```

The above PS command is giving all the deployment details in the resource group. But I want to get the deployment details whatever I have deployed through the Azure DevOps CD pipeline.

For Example:

1. In the release - 1, I have deployed below resources:

   ```
   AppService-Deployment
   Storage-Deployment
   Service Bus-Deployment
   ```

   I want to send the email with the above three deployment details
2. In the release -2, I have deployed below resources:

   ```
   SQL-Deployment
   Cosmos-Deployment
   ```

   I want to send the email with the above two deployment details

So, can anyone suggest me how to do this?

Comment: filter the results?

Comment: You can look into Azure Event Grid (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/overview). This can be of help to you. Especially look at azure resource group as event source (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/event-grid/event-schema-resource-groups)

Comment: Thanks @Tiklu, do you have any sample code?

Comment: I will have to check this and get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

When you use ARM templates to deploy resources, you can set the deployment name in the ARM template deployment task.

[image]

Then, you can [get the deployment by name](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.resources/Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment?view=azps-5.2.0#example-2--get-a-deployment-by-name) when you get deployment details in the PowerShell task.

```
 $deployments = Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment -ResourceGroupName  $resourceGroupName -Name $deploymentName | Sort-Object Timestamp -Descending
```

Comment: Walter, But I'm not using ARM template deployment task. I'm using custom PowerShell script to deploy the ARM templates.

Comment: Walter, Can you please provide sample cmd to get last 30 minutes deployment details using `Get-AzResourceGroupDeployment` cmd.